# Using stacknavigator in TabNavigator

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I wanna use `stacknavigation` in `TabNavigator` in react native with `reactnavigation`
but I have a problem when it's running. It changes automatically to screen which has `stacknavigation` and push on screen in stack

```
import {
TabNavigator,StackNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';
import main from '../screen/main'

const stack = StackNavigator({
Main: {screen: main},
Profile: {screen: main},
});

export const TabBar = TabNavigator({
Main: {screen: main},
Setup: {screen: stack},
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => TabBar  );
```

I means that when app is started and after I change tab bar screen to setup and when I want to comeback it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows the wrong result because the name of Tabnavigator and  StackNavigator is the same.
 so it can't detect the correct navigating.change the name of one of the navigators (Tab navigator or Stacknavigator)
I changed Tabnavigator.

 The correct code is here:

```
const stack = StackNavigator({
Main: {screen: main},
Profile: {screen: main},
});

export const TabBar = TabNavigator({
Main2: {screen: main},   
Setup: {screen: stack},
});
```

Comment: thank you very much . your solution is so useful .you are my hero @eshagh-moutabi